# Multiple-select form and query django

Tags: python, django

One of my fields in my model has a choice field:

```
STATUS = Choices(
   ('first', _('car')),
   ('second', _('motorcycle')),
   ('third', _('bicycle')),
)
```

My filter function looks like this:

```
choice = request.GET.get('choice')

vehicles = vehicles.filter(status=choice).order_by('-date_posted')
```

The filter works, when I select only one choice, but when I am trying to select more than one choice it only catches the last one selected.

The query looks like that:

```
?choice=first&choice=second
```

Any idea how to make it, so it would display items, based on more than one choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`.getlist(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) to obtain the *list* of options, and then use the [**`__in`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) to retrieve the vehicles where the status is one of the elements in the list:

```
choices = request.GET.getlist('choice')

vehicles = vehicles.filter(status__in=choices).order_by('-date_posted')
```